How to disable Mosaico templates?
After using Mosaico for some time, we have a list of templates. For traditional mailing and HTML-letters, we can go into civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1 and both delete or disable old templates.
For Mosaico templates, it only seems to be possible to delete: civicrm/mosaico-template-list
How can we just disable the templates, and not delete them?
(And yes, I know of the possibility to hide base templates civicrm/admin/setting/mosaico?reset=1 It is not the base templates, but the templates I want to hide)

The functionality disable a mosaico template is not possible in the current version. Deleting the template is the only option
